# jQuery .validate() | Required Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I'm creating a form that requires validation for a mobile number and a home number.

The way the form works is that if the user selects the last option only, the home number appears. If they select all three, only mobile is required and the same if they only select option 1 and 2.

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/Qn2fJ/91/) of the options without the validation ( it's too much to put into a jsfiddle )

The trouble I'm having is if the user selects all three options, my submission won't work due to the form being invalid as the home number is not filled out. Even though the home number input isn't displaying, it's set up as a rule in my validation rules as `required: true`

I tried adding and removing the attribute within the markup and that works fine however, it's getting validation to do the same based on selection.

e.g If the user selects Option 3 - Home number is required, js validate is required.
If the user selects all three, Option 1 & 2 or Option 1 or 2 on their own then Home number is not required, js validate is not required.

Here is my code for the validation:

```
$j(self.formID).validate({
        debug: self.debug,
        onclick: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        ignore: ".ignore", // Forces override of hidden elements!
        rules: {
         'Oi_TNXZOWkSwgQjRc95mjg' : { /* First Name */
            required: true
          }, 
          'n4JLI3V4FEqxrgjRc95nvA' : { /* Last Name */
              required: true
          },
          '48r6KevWQkGNIgjRc95owg' : { /* mobile phone number */
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 14
          },
          '4iO6Mosk_kyq8QjRc95qFQ' : { /* home phone number */
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 14
          },
          'TQG9r0MSCEqNcgjPWNA-sA' : { /* Region */
              requiredSelect: true
          },
          't9Cn1rKcn0KhqQjRc95t-A' : { /* Terms and conditions */
              required: true
          }
        }

  });
};
```

Here is my code adding and removing the attribute:

```
showHomeNumber: function() {

        var homeNumber = $j('.home-number'),
            homeRequired = $j('.home-number').find('input'),
            fixedPlan = $j('.fixed'),
            mobileNumber = $j('.mobile-number'),
            planOptions = $j('.account-options li');

        planOptions.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //If all three are selected show mobile, hide home
            if( $j('.active').length > 1) {
                mobileNumber.show();
                homeNumber.hide();
                homeRequired.removeAttr('required');
            } else if ( fixedPlan.hasClass('active') ) {
                //If select Fixed show only home 
                homeNumber.toggleClass('home-number-active');
                homeNumber.show();
                //Add Required attribute for validation
                homeRequired.prop('required', true);
                mobileNumber.hide();
                //If select last option only, hide mobile
                mobileNumber.toggleClass('mobile-number-inactive');
            } else {
                homeNumber.hide();
                //Remove required attribute for validation
                homeRequired.removeAttr('required');
                mobileNumber.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: FYI, the plugin will ignore hidden elements by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was this! required: '#idorname:visible'

```
'48r6KevWQkGNIgjRc95owg' : { /* mobile phone number */
            required: '48r6KevWQkGNIgjRc95owg:visible',
            digits: true,
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 14
          },
          '4iO6Mosk_kyq8QjRc95qFQ' : { /* home phone number */
            required: '4iO6Mosk_kyq8QjRc95qFQ:visible',
            digits: true,
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 14
          },
```